# How to check isAuthenticated in symfony 1.4 from external PHP file ?

Tags: php, session, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How to check `isAuthenticated` or `isLogged` in **symfony 1.4** from external PHP file?

External PHP file located in `/web/js/filemanager.php`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass isAuthenticated to another external php file is to pass an object of sfUser class

@app/frontend/module/indexAction.class.php

```
<?php

class modulenameAction extends sfAction
{
  public function execute($request)
  {
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $sample = new Sample();
    $sample
      ->setUser($user)
      ->setOtherFunction($blabla)
      ->setOtherFunction($blabla);

    if ($sample->result()) {
      return $this->renderText('Authenticated');
    } else return $this->renderText('Not authenticated');
  }
}
```

Then about your Sample class

```
<?php

class Sample
{
  private $user;

  public function setUser($user)
  {
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
  }

  public function result()
  {
    if ($this->user->isAuthenticated())
    {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```